# Twisted reactor cpu usage

Tags: python, twisted

I'm using epoll reactor and sample HTTP Proxy realization.

From another process a execute ~30 HTTP requests per second and twisted process is consuming 10% cpu

The profiler output is:

```
         937706 function calls (934675 primitive calls) in 59.988 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time
   List reduced from 312 to 15 due to restriction <15>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   59.988   59.988 base.py:1167(run)
        1    0.076    0.076   59.988   59.988 base.py:1172(mainLoop)
    12697   55.456    0.004   59.253    0.005 epollreactor.py:169(doPoll)
    13553    0.086    0.000    3.797    0.000 log.py:71(callWithLogger)
    13553    0.096    0.000    3.691    0.000 log.py:66(callWithContext)
    13553    0.047    0.000    3.481    0.000 context.py:117(callWithContext)
    13553    0.067    0.000    3.426    0.000 context.py:61(callWithContext)
    13552    0.095    0.000    3.359    0.000 posixbase.py:544(_doReadOrWrite)
     5454    0.097    0.000    1.736    0.000 tcp.py:182(doRead)
     5453    0.167    0.000    1.639    0.000 basic.py:543(dataReceived)
    12697    0.095    0.000    0.587    0.000 base.py:762(runUntilCurrent)
     4453    0.025    0.000    0.574    0.000 http.py:495(rawDataReceived)
     6000    0.036    0.000    0.547    0.000 http.py:1515(lineReceived)
     2000    0.029    0.000    0.454    0.000 tcp.py:371(doConnect)
     5098    0.104    0.000    0.428    0.000 abstract.py:212(doWrite)


         937706 function calls (934675 primitive calls) in 59.988 CPU seconds

   Ordered by: internal time
   List reduced from 312 to 15 due to restriction <15>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
    12697   55.456    0.004   59.253    0.005 epollreactor.py:169(doPoll)
    59101    0.277    0.000    0.277    0.000 <string>:1(fileno)
     5098    0.252    0.000    0.252    0.000 tcp.py:212(writeSomeData)
    24453    0.198    0.000    0.198    0.000 __init__.py:1230(getEffectiveLevel)
     5453    0.167    0.000    1.639    0.000 basic.py:543(dataReceived)
     5098    0.104    0.000    0.428    0.000 abstract.py:212(doWrite)
     5454    0.097    0.000    1.736    0.000 tcp.py:182(doRead)
    13553    0.096    0.000    3.691    0.000 log.py:66(callWithContext)
    12697    0.095    0.000    0.587    0.000 base.py:762(runUntilCurrent)
    13552    0.095    0.000    3.359    0.000 posixbase.py:544(_doReadOrWrite)
    13553    0.086    0.000    3.797    0.000 log.py:71(callWithLogger)
        1    0.076    0.076   59.988   59.988 base.py:1172(mainLoop)
    16556    0.074    0.000    0.074    0.000 context.py:86(getContext)
    17451    0.073    0.000    0.094    0.000 epollreactor.py:71(_add)
    17098    0.068    0.000    0.085    0.000 epollreactor.py:112(_remove)
```

What is wrong? Why twisted perfomance is so poor here?

Source code being tested applied

```
import hotshot, hotshot.stats

from twisted.internet import epollreactor
epollreactor.install()

from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web import http
from twisted.web.proxy import Proxy

factory = http.HTTPFactory()
factory.protocol = Proxy

reactor.listenTCP(18001, factory)

reactor.callLater(60, reactor.stop)
prof = hotshot.Profile("stones.prof")
prof.start()
reactor.run()
prof.close()
```

Comment: Your profiles clearly show you're using poll, not epoll, though this is likely not relevant to your question.

Comment: I'm sorry for this. It was one of experiments with reactor, but cpu load was the same. I'll update profile log not to confuse anyone.

Comment: Apart from that, this question is like going to a car mechanic and asking why your car makes a funny noise when you make a left turn, but not bringing your car for him to look at.  Where's the source code, and why do you think it should perform better than it does?

Comment: The source code has been added. It is using the standart class so no as interesting as it could be. As the only thing it does is proxing http requests there is no any reason for such high load.

Comment: You shouldn't measure performance based on cpu usage. Do you want your server to eat as much CPU as possible, or to respond to as many requests as possible?

Comment: How are you testing this proxy server?  Perhaps your client is bottlenecked at 30 requests/second.  Or perhaps the bottleneck is the network itself, fetching the pages being requested?  Some simple tests of all-localhost traffic with a fast client on my rather underpowered laptop produce results of around 200 requests/second.  Or perhaps you're testing on hardware slower than a 1200MHz Celeron?

Comment: i've done httperf tests and got 400rps per cpu core. The hardware is 2400MHz xeon

Comment: Why Twisted's performance is "so poor" here is because that's how quickly the implementation can do the task you've set it.  I'm not sure why you expected it to perform better, but it seems like this question is only about your expectations, not about anything technical.

Comment: I'm afraid you're right here. according to given replies, i'll correct my expectations. Thank you all for help.